# Is it possible to have different filters in each tab in the same custom report?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm building a custom report using google analytics, a report that has 3 different tabs.

I want to apply a different filter to each tab but when I change the filter in any of them, it automatically changes the filter in the other tabs.

Is there a way of doing this or do I necessarily need to create another custom report to apply different filters?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) filters let you

> restrict the data that appears in the *report*

meaning they apply to the report as a whole; it is not possible to have filters per tab. You do need to create different custom reports for each filter configuration.